# How to Display Python Argparse Command Line for Users

Tags: python, argparse

Python can be daunting for non-programmers. Should argparse make it clear to to users that python needs to be typed before the rest of the usage line? If so what is the convention?

The Argparse Tutorial example: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

**prog.py**

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.parse_args()
```

**Output**

```
$ python prog.py --help
usage: prog.py [-h]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Comment: There will always be *some* people for which any reasonable example is "too daunting". If you tell them to type exactly what it says, they will start with the `$`.

Comment: Logically speaking it would not make sense. They already have to use python to get your output in the first place. What type of users is your program aimed at? Technical? Semi? Or not at all?

Comment: Maybe but surely most would start after usage:. Can be done - "To change [the] default behavior, another value can be supplied using the `prog=` argument to `ArgumentParser:`" @Chuk - Aimed at python clueless - I've seen them run before.

Comment: What if `prog.py` has a `#!` first line?

Comment: That's the answer. Added `#! /usr/bin/env python` and don't need to prefix command line with `python`.  :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following as first line - kudos @hpaulj

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: This only works on *nix-like systems, and only if your script is executable.

Comment: No - see my last comment below question comments. Tested under win7 and win10.